# Cross Browser check mobile devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, android-emulator, cross-browser

Short of buying the full compliment of: iPad, iPhone, android tablet and android phone(s) .... and the rest ... is there any reliable way to browser test some of these for how a website looks, particularly the ipad? I read somewhere, csstricks I think, that the ipad doesnt generally need any special treatment; is this the case.

Comment: similar question might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464089/simulators-emulators-for-mobile-browser-testing note i have never used them just heard about them

Comment: The iPad will handle most things. Look into w3c and webkit. You may also be interested to know that the webbrowser will have access to the Graphics card and can do animations using the webkit css tags. Quite reliably as well.

Comment: @VolureDarkAngel - thanks for that - i am aware of w3c .... what in particular are you referring to; standards in general ?

Comment: ipad is fairly complete standards compliant browser. I have not found a page (that displays non mobile to ipad) that has acted different on the ipad then on the safari browser on the mac. Short of some of the obvious mouseover and equivalent activities that the ipad does not have.. And some of those function as well.

Comment: If you get XCode 4 on apple you are given an iPad Simulator that you would be able to do some testing with

Comment: @VolureDarkAngel thanks - great information - very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well This wont show you how the page is rendered. But it will let you determine how a page is downloaded when a certain device browses to it.

[User Agent Switcher (Firefox Plugin)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/)

You will need the user agent that you are trying to handle for. But this is how the servers tell what device they are dealing with. This way you can customize your code to handle for certain scenarios and verify that the html is correct on the client end.

Again this will likely not display how the browser would see it. But will give you the knowledge that it did what you intended it to do. (Custom CSS or custom layout or whatever else)

As for testing on the devices, since they may all have their own little quirks the closest thing you can hope for is finding emulators for the devices you want to find out about. (and hope they accurately emulate the quirks)

Answer (score 2):

There is a service that does this very thing:
http://crossbrowsertesting.com/

Comment: thanks - that's great but a little out of my budget at the moment unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

The iPad and stock Android browsers are fairly smart about displaying content. It's not a huge deal if you can't get your hands on a device to test how it *looks.*

If you are trying to test a site that's *specifically targets* mobile devices (if it uses touch events, for example), you should probably invest in or borrow a device.

An emulator is better than nothing, however. Try the following:

- [Android's SDK includes a browser](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
- [Opera Mobile has an emulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/)
- [Mobile Firefox also has an emulator](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/#desktop)
- To test in Opera Mini either install it on a Android virtual machine or use [MicroEmulator](http://www.microemu.org/) and download the [.jad file](http://m.opera.com/) (this will also work for [UCWeb](http://ucweb.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

you can try http://www.testize.com service that provides cross-devices testing for about 10 devices, iPhone 3, 4, 5; iPads and Android

They also provide you a report with discovered site issues